# IdentityUser connected to CreatedBy and ChangedBy

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am using the latest build of entity-framework-core.

Every entity I have defined in my dbcontext contains a createdby and changedby field of type IdentityUser. This works fine for most entities but my IdentityUser entity (tableName:ApplicationUser) has two connected entity fields: Culture and TWRole ..

If I now try to add my migration I get the error "Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'TWRole.CreatedBy' of type 'ApplicationUser'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'"

I tried various configurations in my OnModelCreating method but i am not getting it to work.

How can I get this to work as expected ?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>, IEntity<long>
{
    [DisplayName("CreatedBy")]
    public long? CreatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NoTranslation]
    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("ChangedBy")]
    public long? ChangedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChangedById")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NoTranslation]
    public ApplicationUser ChangedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to share the class definitions of ApplicationUser and TWRole fo us to help

Comment: If createdby and changedby are from type IdentityUser, then changing both to ApplicationUser should fix it. You can avoid these issues by not mixing the Identity context and business context.

Comment: @DanielRothig I added the extra information.